# Does $x$ always exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $m$, $n$ and $p$ are fixed positive integers such that $p$ is a prime and $\text{gcd}(m,n) = \text{gcd}(n,p) = 1$, does an integer $x$ always exist, such that,

$$ nx \equiv m \pmod p $$

I was looking at modular equations involving rationals and this question came to mind.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: gcd$(n,p) = 1$ is sufficient. If that's not true, $\text{gcd}(n,p)|\text{gcd}(m,n)$ would be sufficient.

Comment: But how do I show that such an integer always exists?

Comment: Because the $p$ residues $n,2n,\dots,pn$ must all be distinct and hence just a permutation of $0,1,\dots,p-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need $\gcd(n,p)=1$ and $p$ need not be prime.

Indeed, by Bézout’s identity, there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $an+bp=1$, so you have $an=1-bp$ and
$$
anx=(1-bp)x=x-bpx\equiv x\pmod{p}
$$
Thus you get your desired solution to $nx\equiv m\pmod{p}$ by
$$
x\equiv am\pmod{p}
$$
If you want the minimum positive solution, it will be of the form
$$
am+kp
$$
for a suitable integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

The elements modulo $p$ forment a field $\mathbb F_p$ in which all number $n$ non multiple of $p$ (i.e. $\text{gcd}(n,p) = 1$) represents un element which is invertible in $\mathbb F_p$. Besides $nx \equiv m \pmod p$ with numbers is equivalent to $nx=m$ with the respective elements in $\mathbb F_p$. Therefore
$$nx=m\Rightarrow \boxed{ x=n^{-1}\cdot m}$$

Examples in $\mathbb F_{13}$ $$3x=2\Rightarrow x=3^{-1}\cdot2=9\cdot2=5\\3x=6\Rightarrow x=3^{-1}\cdot6=9\cdot6=2$$

You can see in these two examples that the condition **$\text{gcd}(m,n) =1$ is not necessary**.

Comment: Yes $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field, but shouldn't you explain why? After all, the only difficult point in showing that it is a field is precisely what the OP is asking.

Comment: $xy=0$ in $\mathbb F_p$ implies $x$ or $y$ should be zero so.....

Comment: Yes. That is the key idea: if $p$ divides $xy$ then it must divide $x$ or $y$. If you have that, you don't need to invoke finite fields.

Comment: Why not if this fact is quite well known?

Comment: It is a question of level. No one familiar with finite fields is likely to ask why $nx=m\bmod p$ has a solution!